# How to fix Call to undefined function get_woocommerce_currency() in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fatal-error

I'm developing a custom shipping plugin to my WooCommerce website.

I want to change shipping method to my custom method if and only if the user's currency is USD. Apart from USD, I'm using LKR as my other currency unit. If the currency is in LKR different shipping method should be applied.

So I tried to check whether the user's current base currency is in USD by using this code in my plugin.php file,

My plugin.php code includes in -> `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin`

```
 if ( 'USD' !== get_woocommerce_currency() ) {
    echo 'Hello  ';
    //my action
}
```

So now every time I run this code I'm getting a fatal error saying

```
Call to undefined function get_woocommerce_currency()
```

Then I tried including the option.php ,

```
include_once('wp-includes/option.php');
```

still getting the same error message.

How to fix it and why I'm getting that error?

What I want to do is just to check user's current currency and activate the plugin if the currency is only in USD.

Thanks.

Comment: Undefined function means the function doesn't exists, go into your wp-includes/options.php and do a search for the function by ctrl-F and type the function name

Comment: Please see these hooks lists https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-get_woocommerce_currency.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for your issue will depend on how/when you're calling those lines of code you have.

One is if you've added a hook on `woocommerce_init` this won't be a problem.

A very very simple example to show what I mean.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'wc_init' );
function wc_init(){
    // get_woocommerce_currency() will not throw error here.
}
```

If you're making a plugin that should work alongside with WooCommerce, I suggest you run your plugin init inside a function hook to `woocommerce_init`.

---

I'm not really sure what you're up to. But if you're just interested in the currency, might as well just do this:

```
$currency = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_currency', get_option( 'woocommerce_currency' ) );
if ( 'USD' !== $currency ) {
    echo 'Hello  ';
    //my action
}
```

Again, working alongside with WooCommerce, you should use `'woocommerce_init'` to hook your function.

---

**update 3**

```
function add_chalitha_shipping_method( $methods ) {
    if ( 'USD' == get_woocommerce_currency() ) {
         $methods[] = 'test_Shipping_Method';
    }
    return $methods;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Reigel, even though your code done the trick when I use it my checkout section remains  keep loading, does it overwrite other woocommerce functions?

Comment: You should update your original post above with what you have done. Because my code above will not do anything, whatever you put in there is another story. So I can't tell what's the problem.

Comment: hooking a function to `woocommerce_init` will just make sure WooCommerce is ready. So all functions of WooCommerce will exist.

Comment: I have added my complete code. What i want to do is activate this shipping method only if the currency is in USD. are there have any other way to do that apart from checking the currency?

Comment: I have not checked your code thoroughly because it's very long. But `add_chalitha_shipping_method` adds the shipping method. You should put the `if` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `get_woocommerce_currency()` function you should check if the function exists or not. The `get_woocommerce_currency()` exists in `wc-core-functions.php` file.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'get_woocommerce_currency' ) ) { 
  require_once '/includes/wc-core-functions.php'; 
} 


$currency_code = get_woocommerce_currency();

if ( 'USD' !== $currency_code  ) {
      echo 'Hello  ';
     //my action
}
```

The `get_woocommerce_currency()` is a WooCommerce's function. You will find it in `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes` directory.

Comment: require_once '/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php'; is this correct path?

Comment: add as require_once '../woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php';

Comment: I have added my complete code so far been done without the currency checking part,